# android gridview change item text

Tags: java, android, gridview

Ive got some gridView and some function which is called when a message arrives from server. In this function I get the values from server and I want to write this value in specific item in the gridView.
The problem is I dont have any idea how can I rewrite text of som Item in the gridView and I couldn find any answer on the internet :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to to add the received data into arraylist which you used to populate your grid view . You can add the received data into any position of arraylist as you need.

Then update the Arrayadapter using the following command

```
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand up to some point. In my expatiation i think your set by using `adapter` right. So the simple solution is once you get the new items for a grid. call the `setadapter` again. Then that will set the new items. Try it once.

Actually i have to comment out but i don't have that much points.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but Ill go with Arun Antoneys solution because it seems to me that its quicker just to notify the change for the adapter than creating whole new adapter... anyway I appreciate your help :)